# Reverse Engineering ethics

Tags: ethics

As a freelancer, in what circumstances and with what provisions (if any) would it be ethical to reverse engineer an app that a client says they own, but do not have the source code for? Should you just take their word for it, or should you make provision for checking if they're being honest about it or not.

In the instance I am thinking of. The reason given when I asked was that the guy they hired to make the app had not given them the source code, and not being technical people they hadn't asked for it, and they cannot contact him.

But I'm asking the question in general terms.

Comment: In your situation, you've asked the client why they don't have the source code, and they gave you a reason. It seems now you just have to ask whether you'll "accept" that reasoning or not. What other form of checking did you have in mind?

Comment: @Brandin Check up on the company, check what you can about the app.

Comment: Even if we ignore the legal aspect, wouldn't the ethics of the situation also depend on whether the contract for the original developer included an IP transfer? If they didn't think to get the source code that tells me they probably didn't think to use a software transfer agreement either in which case you're legally and ethically in the wrong.

Comment: yep, a bit beside the point though. The question is whether you take their word for it or not. If they're dodgy and you ask that, they'll just say they have that agreement somewhere. Then for you to demand to see it makes you look like you think they're lying. That could go in any direction. If you could read their minds it would negate the whole question.

Comment: This situation really seems like it will have to end up being your judgment call. The phrase "take their word for it" can imply that you're switching off your human reasoning and just processing requests like a computer would. Don't do that. If you feel like they're not being straightforward with you, you have the option not to do business. But I think this is more about prudence than about ethics.

Comment: @Brandin The reason it seems (to me) to be an ethical question, is precisely because the only thing I would have to be prudent about is getting paid. I could do the job with no worries about legalities. But having software on the market myself, I'd be reluctant to take the chance that some other poor chap is being shafted. I actually could have made a LOT of money on this but turned it down because it didn't 'feel' right, and it's been bugging me ever since. Because they'll just go elsewhere and someone else will do it.

Comment: If the app is publicly available you should be able to check on who owns it.

Comment: @DJClayworth so checking is the right thing to do?

Comment: @Kilisi If it is easy to check you should do it. Not doing your due diligence when a simple check is possible could be considered unethical. If you get these kinds of requests, you might also consider establishing your own official policy for reverse engineering requests or even for projects in general. Then you can refer to this policy for guidelines in such situations.

Comment: @Brandin Sounds more like an answer than a comment

Comment: @Kilisi Regarding your first comment: that's what you get when you provide a specific scenario :). While this is the Workplace a lot of people came here from SO so you're more likely to get answers (and debate) on the intricacies of software ownership than the general question "*Is it ethical to use a tool when I can't verify that it was legally purchased?*" Seems like that could be a question in its own right though.

Comment: I also want to point out, normal discussions of "reverse engineering" are applied to situations where a party A wants to reverse engineer the product of party B, without B's knowledge or consent. The ethics and legality of this are complicated and hotly debated. However, the situation we have here is not at all like this, so all of that debate is basically irrelevant. Basically, "reverse engineering" in this case may be a bit of a red herring in finding a good answer.

Comment: @Brandin But this could very well be that exact scenario if in fact they don't really own the product, you're taking them at their word that they do.

Comment: @Kilisi I guess I'm saying that if they actually do own the product, it is not really fair to call it "reverse engineering" in the normal sense of discussion. And if they don't own the product, the question of whether the specific reverse engineering is ethical or not is not easy to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should you just take their word for it

No, a general rule of thumb is not to believe anything unsupported a stranger tells you when the outcome of convincing you benefits their agenda. This holds true whether it's someone in a van offering you a lollipop while you're walking home from school, or a potential client wanting some reverse engineering done. A judgement call needs to be made based on what they're trying to convince you to do. But don't assume honesty straight away.

> should you make provision for checking if they're being honest about it or not.

Yes, you should do what you can, either that or just decline the job. You may not get definitive information, but if you find enough to allay your suspicions, that's all that's needed. This isn't about legality. One way is to check on the company and the person doing the requesting. I have found that a bit of time on google and looking at websites usually gives me enough information to make a 'gut' judgement call.

Eg,. it might be a solid looking company who have had the app for quite a while, but you can't find any connection between the person requesting the job and the company. Or worse still you find a connection but the person no longer works there.

Comment: It's worth noting that as a freelancer, you are entirely the person at risk doing the work. The company you are working on behalf of could counter-sue you if the original developer sues them for any sort of IP infringement if the company turns out to be dishonest. This is why professional liability insurance exists - because things can and do go wrong due to bad decisions and someone has to pay.

Comment: Very good point

Answer (score 5):

Your potential customer might have licensed the software and asks you to reverse engineer it (in other words, write equivalent software) with the intent of ripping off the original developer. In that case it's highly unlikely that paying you will be cheaper than paying the original developer, who, after all, *has* the source code and therefore could do the job much cheaper than you.

As soon as you are talking about money, you will find out. If they expect you to be cheaper than the original developer, negotiations will stop when you talk about money. If the genuinely messed up and lost the source code, they will pay your price.

Since you asked ethics and not legality: If what you do isn't robbing the original developer (because he or she cannot be contacted, for example), it's fine ethically.

Comment: In answer to your first two paragraphs, I have to disagree, it's easier and much less expensive to make an equivalent piece of software if you don't need to do all the planning that's involved with creating and tweaking and upgrading something from scratch. In answer to your third paragraph, I agree, but is it ethical to take the clients word on the matter without checking in some way? As a freelancer quite often you have no real idea about the client, you may have just met them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask yourself one vital question *Do they own the copyright for the code?*

This is a difficult and maybe an expensive question to be absolutely sure of an answer. You cannot rely on their word. So as a freelance programmer are you will to take the chance?

Personally I would not. It is not worth the risk.

Comment: I don't think it's realistic to expect a freelancer to investigate copyrights just to work on a project. Besides, if the company has violated someone's copyright, it's that company who has done that violation, not the freelance programmer.

Comment: That was my point. But doing it as freelance is it the company that is going to pay you in the future that is going to take a possible fall. Or can the company just walk away. Either way it is doing to be a difficult thing to sort out in court and therefore not worth the risk

Comment: But this risk is still there even if you've got the source code. Or are you going to go through all the source code to see if there's something possibly infringing before agreeing to work on it? For evaluating legal risks get a legal consultant.

Comment: @Brandin - It is about risk reduction. Nothing in life is risk free. But reverse engineering is very risky IHMO.

Comment: I tend to agree with the sentence "Personally I would not.", it's not the risk I care about, I'm in the third World, good luck trying to prosecute me, it's the ethics of the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Your ethical obligation should be that you are reasonably sure that you are not assisting them to take something they do not have a legal right to.  In a matter like this asking to see their contract with the original author should be a reasonable step in your due diligence and should not be interpreted as a lack of trust in them.  In reality they probably benefit from you ensuring that the action they are wanting taken is legal.

Do your due diligence and make sure that **you** are convinced they own this code.

Comment: Sounds reasonable